# Sibling's child affecting sibling on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a submenu when hovering over an anchor. Tried `.expand:hover ~ .submenu` or `.expand:hover + .submenu` but they don't seem to work because anchor is not a direct sibling of submenu. I have to hover over that particular li anchor Is there an HTML/CSS way of doing it. I know I can use JS to sort it out, but is there an HTML/CSS method?

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.submenu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.expand:hover ~ .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class"menu">
  <li class="menu-item expand"><a href="">EXPAND\/</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="submenu">
  <p>submenu</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Move the `expand` class to `<ul class="menu">` and your problem should be fixed ;). You're missing an "=" sign in your HTML (`<ul class="menu">`) by the way

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the HTML structure since there is no way to access a parent element with CSS only. For example, move your submenu to be a descendant of the menu item. JS is not a bad idea, though...

```css
.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.submenu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
}

.expand:hover ~ .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class"menu">
  <li class="menu-item expand"><a href="">EXPAND\/</a></li>
  <div class="submenu">
    <p>submenu</p>
  </div>
</ul>
```